# Android: Set interval in SeekBar

Tags: android

In my application I have a `Seekbar` that is shown in a dialog.
Now I wanna set the interval and step in the `Seekbar`. The interval should be 0-250 and each step should be 5 minutes.

so far this is my code:

```
public class seekActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnSeekBarChangeListener {
    SeekBar seekbar;
    Button button;
    TextView textview;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //set up main content view
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //this button will show the dialog
        Button button1main = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01main);
        button1main.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //set up dialog
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.maindialog);
        dialog.setTitle("This is my custom dialog box");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        seekbar = (SeekBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        textview = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        dialog.show();
    }
    public class SeekBarPreference {
    }
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
    boolean fromUser) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        textview.setText(progress + "");
    }
    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    };
}
```

Could anyone give me some tips/code how to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your question how to cause it to take a step every 5 minutes?

Comment: no sorry if its unclear, as default, as you move the seekbar it takes one step at a time: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. What i want is it to move 5 steps a time: 5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40.

If this is hard to do, please just help me with the interval!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Instead of doing this why not just set the max value of the SeekBar to 50 (250/5) and then do whatever conversion is necessary from the SeekBar values to "real" values?

Comment: old question but still. Set the seekbar max to the amount of steps that you want it to have. The seekbar logik does the rest for you.

Answer (score 45):

You have to just update the onProgressChanged method as follows.

```
int stepSize = 5;
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
    progress = ((int)Math.round(progress/stepSize))*stepSize;
    seekBar.setProgress(progress);
    textview.setText(progress + "");

}
```

Comment: As `progress` and `stepSize` are already of type `int`, `Math.round` is not necessary: `(progress/stepSize) * stepSize` suffices.

Comment: stack over flow... any changes in seekbar will affect it self again

Answer (score 2):

If you use

```
Math.round((float)progress / stepSize) * stepSize
```

your threshold will be in the middle of two steps

If you use

```
progress / stepSize * stepSize
```

the slider will always jump to the left step. This will just cut the decimals in the division.