# How can we limit seekbar to make progress in fixed steps

Tags: android, progress, seekbar, android-progressbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Set interval in SeekBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431335/android-set-interval-in-seekbar)

I have a seekbar with max value as 100
So the total span of values it can take is 0-100.

but my requirement is that the progress shown on seekbar should only be in fixed steps.
i.e. I only want my seekbar to take these values 1, 10 , 20, 30, 40, ....90, 100
and not any value between these steps.

how can I limit my seekbar to work in this manner?

Please help

Comment: Why not make your seekBar go from 1 to 10 ? That would just be the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

store the possible values in an array and use the current seek-bar value as the array-index.

Pseudo-code

```
int[] values = {1, 10 , 20, 30, 40, ....90, 100};
int current = values[ seekbar.getValue() ];
```

So for if seekbar.getValue() == 1 your current == 10.

Answer (score 4):

You can make your seekbar's max as 10 and while displaying the selected value, get the current progress and multiply with 10.

Comment: imho, this is simplest solution