# How to give intervals to a Seekbar in Android

Tags: seekbar

I'm Making android App using Seek Bar
Here I was trying to give intervals to a Seek bar in Android. 
likewise 0 25 50 100  (i.e it should progress likewise 0 25 50 75 100)
Is it possible? Can any 1 help me?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: my app's seek bar is working fine. But i want interval for it likewise 0 25 50 100

Answer (score 8):

It will work if you edit the onProgressChanged method like so:

```
@Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

        int stepSize = 25;

        progress = (progress/stepSize)*stepSize;
        seekBar.setProgress(progress);

        sliderText.setText("" + progress);
    }
```

taken tips from here:

[Android: Set interval in SeekBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431335/android-set-interval-in-seekbar)

Comment: note in this code that "seekBar" is not the SeekBar that I defined in onCreate, it's a object parameter of the onProgressChanged method

Comment: The best answer I've found on the internet. It'll help me to make Google Allo-like button with slider

Comment: I don't think this is correct because:         progress = (progress/stepSize)*stepSize;
the stepSize's cancel out meaning this is the same as progress = progress ...?