# seekbar interval

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

I am integrating the Android `seekbar` widget as a distance bar going from 1-100 KM. Currently, the bar moves in a fixed interval 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 etc. I want the interval to be flexible and go from 1,2,5,10,15,25,50,75,100.

I have been told that this is not possible. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Set interval in SeekBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431335/android-set-interval-in-seekbar)

Comment: Unfortunately not. That post refers to a fixed internal.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10435521/8112541

Comment: This post concerns a fixed interval of 5. This is not what I am interested in.